# Setting up elasticsearch issue

Tags: java, linux, search, terminal, elasticsearch

I'm trying to install elasticsearch and I am getting this message.

I type in terminal linux:

```
sh elasticsearch -f@
```

and get:

```
elasticsearch: line 141: /bin/java: is a directory
elasticsearch: line 141: exec: /bin/java: cannot execute: Success
```

Comment: `elasticsearch: line 141: /bin/java: is a directory` - is it a directory? if that's a case then your java installation is not correct

Answer (score 1):

To run ElasticSearch from linux navigate to the upper ElasticSearch directory. So that the bin directory is visible.

Then run the following command -

```
bin/elasticsearch (background)
```

or

```
bin/elasticsearch -f (foreground)
```

Comment: Still getting the same error, could it be a JAVA problem, may be I haven't install Java correctly.

Comment: It would give you an explicit `No Java Home variable set` if this was the case. Run `java -version` to ensure you have.

Comment: Here is a gist on installing ElasticSearch - https://gist.github.com/wingdspur/2026107